# LM 56 temperature trip point resistor selection

Tags: integrated-circuit, thermal

I'm having a hard time grasping on how to calculate the values for resistors R1 R2 and R3 in the typical application diagram pg.2 in the data sheet. Could some one break down the calculation steps down for me? Maybe ELI 5? I need OUT 1 triggering at 2 deg c and OUT 2 at 40 deg c.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm56.pdf

[image: Typical Application]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated, but a quick glance over the datasheet suggests that there the value of \$T\$ should be in specified in Celsius degrees for the equations. This is modestly confirmed by the sparse examples given and by another odd detail -- that the value of \$395\:\text{mV}\$ divided by their rate just happens to land on a convenient numeric intersection of Celsius and Fahrenheit temperature scales. That's settled.

All they want you to do is calculate \$V_{\text{T}_1}\$ and \$V_{\text{T}_2}\$ using their convenient formula, \$V\left(T\right)=395\:\text{mV}+T\cdot 6.2\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}\$. You do this twice, once for each of your temperatures. You have two. So you make up two voltage values from them using that formula. This gives you \$V_{\text{T}_1}=V\left(2\:^\circ\text{C}\right)\$ and \$V_{\text{T}_2}=V\left(40\:^\circ\text{C}\right)\$.

With that in hand, you follow their step by step process of computing first \$R_1\$, then \$R_2\$, and then finally \$R_3\$.

$$\begin{align*}
V_{\text{T}_1} &= 395\:\text{mV}+2\:^\circ\text{C}\cdot 6.2\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}=407.4\:\text{mV}\\\\
V_{\text{T}_2} &=395\:\text{mV}+40\:^\circ\text{C}\cdot 6.2\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}=643\:\text{mV}\\\\
R_1 &= V_{\text{T}_1}\:\frac{27\:\text{k}\Omega}{1.25\:\text{V}}\approx 8.8\:\text{k}\Omega\\\\
R_2&=V_{\text{T}_2}\:\frac{27\:\text{k}\Omega}{1.25\:\text{V}}-R_1\approx 5.09\:\text{k}\Omega\\\\
R_3&=27\:\text{k}\Omega-R_1-R_2\approx 13.1\:\text{k}\Omega
\end{align*}$$

It's boiler-plate.

The datasheet also goes into other discussions about offset, sensor, and output errors. But that's a different topic.

---

If you decide on specific resistor values for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and want to still hold to the idea that \$R_3=27\:\text{k}\Omega-R_1-R_2\$, then you can work out the final temperatures for those choices as:

$$\begin{align*}
T_1 &= \frac{R_1\cdot 1.25\:\text{V}-27\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 395\:\text{mV}}{6.2\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}\cdot 27\:\text{k}\Omega}\\\\
T_2 &=\frac{\left(R_1+R_2\right)\cdot 1.25\:\text{V}-27\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 395\:\text{mV}}{6.2\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}\cdot 27\:\text{k}\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

You can then decide if that is close enough for your purposes, given standard resistor values near the calculated ones.